# npm forever não funciona nem localmente nem na hospedagem

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho uma aplicação em node que executo com o comando:

`node server.js`

Mas quando fecho o terminal onde o comando foi executado, a aplicação encerra.

Pesquisando encontrtei pacote npm Forever. 
Fiz a instalação globalmente conforme orientações na pagina, e rodando

`forever server.js`

Acontece a mesma coisa. Fecho a janela e a aplicação encerra. Alguém conhece alguma alternativa para rodar tasks do em background? Será que é alguma incompatibilidade com a versão atual do node?

Comment: Certo... bom.. eu queria algo que funcionasse como no exemplo desse video. 

https://youtu.be/P4mT5Tbx_KE

Nesse video é usado  comando 'hohup npde server.js'

E quando ele fecha a janela do temrinal o servidor continua rodando.

Comment: Acredito que sua pergunta principal tenha sido respondida pelo Joao. Com relação a outro gerenciador de serviços (para produção), você pode utilizar o [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io).

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar `forever start server.js`

De acordo com o site do pacote, faltou a palavra *start* no seu comando, tenta testar e vê se da certo

[Site do Pacote Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Comment: Ah sim.. escrevi errado. Mas mesmo com o start não funciona... nem o Forever nem o exemplo do youtube com o nohup...

Comment: Ele acusa algum erro? Se tiver como você enviar alguma print ou linha de código, que está retornando quando você digita esse comando

Comment: Não dá erro nenhum. É como se eu não estivesse usando o forever. funciona como se eu estivesse simplesmente executando com 'node server.js'. Quando eu fecho a janela do terminal... o aplicativo encerra.

Comment: Tente usar o comando forever apontando para o diretório.Após isso tente usar o comando "forever list" para listar todos os processos rodando